# Creation of Terraform Variables for Nested Objects

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Following is the variable declaration for my terraform module which is used in our cloud and inputs for these variables are obtained via one of the automation solutions. Now, I would like to reproduce one of the issues for which I would like to create a tfvars file from the below variable definition.

**variables.tf:**

```
variable "docker" {
  type = object({
    image_name    = string
    image_location = string
    docker_ports = object({
      internal = number
      external    = number
    })
    rmodelling = object({
      lang  = object({
        version = number
        enabled    = bool
        policy = object({
          identification = string
        })
      })
      impl = object({
        version   = number
        enabled      = bool
        policy = object({
          identification = string
        })
      })
    })
  })
}
```

I have tried something like this, but for the next nested objected I am not quite sure on how those can be put down. Can someone guide or shed some pointers?

**terraform.tfvars:**

```
docker = {
  image_name = "Ubuntu 18.04"
  image_location = "https://registry.jd.com/ubuntu/<custom_location>"
  docker_ports = {
    internal = 80
    external = 443
  }
rmodelling = { ??
???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of a valid value for your `var.docker` is:

```
docker = {
  image_name = "Ubuntu 18.04"
  image_location = "https://registry.jd.com/ubuntu/<custom_location>"
  docker_ports = {
    internal = 80
    external = 443
  }
  rmodelling = { 
      lang = {
            version = 3
            enabled = true
            policy = {
              identification = "test"
            }
      }
      impl = {
        version = 4
        enabled = false
        policy = {
          identification = "test2"
        }      
     }       
  }    

}
```